# Else statement inside for loop won't work

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, max, nested-loops

EDIT: Problem is solved thank you all. I know the problem is not very well explained, sorry for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()

{
    int line=0;
    int longest=0;
    int v1[3][3]={{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{7,8,9}};
    for(int i=0 ; i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2 ;j++ ){
            if(v1[i][j]==0){
                
                int temp=1;
                for(int k=j+1; k< 3; k++){
                    printf("%d\n",k);
                    if( v1[i][k]==0 ){
                        temp++;
                    }
                    if( v1[i][k]=!0 ){
                        if( temp>longest ){
                            longest=temp;
                            line=i+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("line:%d\nlenght:%d",line,longest);
}
```

I have a code like this. When I try to use else statement with if statement, else statement won't work when the requirements inside if statement are not met.

```
                    if( v1[i][k]==0 ){
                        temp++;
                    }
                    else{
                        if( temp>longest ){
                            longest=temp;
                            line=i+1;
                        }
```

But when I use another if statement it would run when v1[i][k]!=0 condition is met.

```
                    if( v1[i][k]==0 ){
                        temp++;
                    }
                    if( v1[i][k]!=0 ){
                        if( temp>longest ){
                            longest=temp;
                            line=i+1;
                        }
```

Comment: Replace `=!` => `!=`. I don't know how you claim it is working.

Comment: The `v1[i][k] = !0` is also *writing* to the array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `v1[i][k] = !0` is a valid statement, that's why it compiles, that's also why the code behaves differently when replacing with else.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I am well aware of this. Compiles != working.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Reopen the question because it has nothing common with the typo.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You are probably right, as the question is about the other code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement

```
if( v1[i][k]=!0 ){
```

there is a typo. There should be

```
if( v1[i][k] != 0 ){
```

But in any case the first and the second programs have a logical error. This if statement

```
if( temp>longest )
```

must be placed outside the inner for loop.

```
for(int k=j+1; k< 3; k++){
```

And moreover the condition in the this loop

```
for(int j=0; j<2 ;j++ ){
```

shall be `j < 3` instead of `j < 2`. Otherwise the situation when a row contains only the last element equal to zero will be ignored.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the for loops can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N][N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 2;
        }
    }
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    int line = 0;
    int longest = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0, k = 1; j < N - longest; j += k, k = 1 )
        {
            if ( a[i][j] == 0 )
            {
                while ( j + k < N && a[i][j + k] == 0 ) ++k;
                
                if ( longest < k )
                {
                    longest = k;
                    line = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    
    if ( line != 0 )
    {
        printf( "line: %d, length: %d\n", line, longest );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "There is no row with elements equal to 0" );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 

line: 7, length: 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace =! with !=
An occasional error difficult to spot.
In C '!=' means "not equal".
While '=!' is a combination of assignment to logical negation.
'x=!0' is the same as 'x=1'

Comment: Is it common? Never encountered. Also some compilers might warn when seeing assignment instead of comparison. And I think the question is in fact about the second snippet.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok maybe not common but definitely not uncommon. It's high voted answer for query about difficult to spot errors. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14269532/4989451

Comment: Compilers can definitely help finding it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HXgseBzH5SBrOGh7 Anyway, as I said, the question is not about this code, but about the other one that does not have this typo

Comment: the question was about second snipnet but when I did what Vlad from Moscow said else statements started working. Probably I was getting an logic error.